# VFY: register1 v4 type 2, wanted 17

Tags: android, dalvik, smali

I have the following Smali code:

```
.method private a(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Bundle;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
.registers 33
move/16 v22, p5
move-object/16 v21, p4
move-object/16 v20, p3
move-object/16 v19, p2
move-object/16 v18, p1
move-object/16 v17, p0
check-cast v21, Ljava/lang/String;
check-cast v20, Ljava/lang/String;
check-cast v19, Landroid/os/Bundle;
check-cast v18, Landroid/content/Context;
check-cast v17, Lcom/clevertap/android/sdk/aa;
move-object/from16 v1, v18
move-object/from16 v2, v19
move-object/from16 v3, v20
move/from16 v4, v22
.line 476

...

invoke-static {v4}, Ljava/lang/Integer;->valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

This is rejected by the Dalvik verifier with the following reason:

```
VFY: register1 v4 type 2, wanted 17
VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x05f0
VFY:  rejected Lcom/clevertap/android/sdk/aa;.a (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Bundle;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
Verifier rejected class Lcom/clevertap/android/sdk/aa;
```

Type 17 is Integer while type 2 means unknown type. Why does the verifier lose the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the offset is `0x05f0`, that `invoke-static` instruction occurs very far down in the method. There is almost certainly code between the top of the method and there that also uses the v4 register.

I recommend using baksmali's `--register-info` functionality, which adds a comment  before/after each instruction with details on the types of registers. You should be able to trace the code backwards and figure out where the type of v4 is coming from.

Comment: Baksmali does not workin with the parameter --register-info: Error occurred while loading class path files. Aborting.
org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPathResolver$ResolveException: org.jf.dexlib2.analy
sis.ClassPathResolver$NotFoundException: Could not find classpath entry /system/
framework/core-libart.jar
        at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPathResolver.<init>(ClassPathResolver.ja
va:138)

Comment: See `baksmali help classpath`. Although, in this case, I don't think you're interested in the exact class type of the regsiter, just in the general type (unknown, integer, reference, etc), so I think an empty classpath (`--bootclasspath ""`) might suffice.